# Display content in two columns (50% each), if content does not fit move column to next row and fill horizontal space

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns

In my project, I want to display content in two columns (50% each), if content does not fit in, then move column to next row and fill horizontal space.

Here are two images to show what I mean.

For short text, display it in two columns:

[image]

When the text does not fit anymore, ie either of the columns are above 50% width, move the 2nd column's content in the next row filling all available horizontal space. Somewhat like this :

[image]

Can this be done only with CSS?

Comment: Use `@media` queries; one of the first results I've come across by searching on Google -> https://codepen.io/irinakramer/pen/jcLlp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` and `white-space: nowrap`

[Fiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/surog1ya/)

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.left,
.right {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  background: lightgreen;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.right {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="left">
   This is a longer text. This is a longer text. 
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  This is a shorter text. 
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="left">
   This is an even longer text. This is an even longer text.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  This is a shorter text. 
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex` it is possible.

Have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a780srjh/)** I've made for you. Simply add more text to see the result.

Just use a `flex-wrap` and do some aligning and justifying of the content.

For this to work in a cross-browser environment, always use an **[Autoprefixer.](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)**

Comment: With this text can grow beyond 50% width before it break line, which it is asked not to

Comment: LGSon, have you even tried adding more text in either of the divs as I described in my answer before commenting?

Comment: Yes, I filled left element with text and it only break when reaching right elements text width (+ padding) ... https://jsfiddle.net/a780srjh/1/ ... which mean the elements are just before break not 50% wide each

Comment: Add `min-width: 50%` to the `div` and it's exactly what I needed.